# Access to a property in a specific resource via sightly

Tags: aem, sling, sightly

I want to access to a specific property in resource.

The main resource hat two children and the app is in the first one. I want to get a property from the second child.

Can i find something like :

```
 ${resource.parent.child[1].valueMap.title}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To start - note that **the order of the children may not be guaranteed**, unless you're using sling:OrderedFolder or some other ordered type. So trying to get the "second" child may not even make sense.

Having said that, there may some valid use cases that I am not thinking of for needing to get the second child -- as far as I can tell you will need to create a Java or JS object and make use of the [Use Api](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/htl/docs/use-api/java.html).

### Simple Example Java object

```java
package apps.your_app.components.yourComponent;

import com.adobe.cq.sightly.WCMUsePojo;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class Model extends WCMUsePojo {

    @Override
    public void activate() throws Exception {
        //do some stuff if needed
    }

    public Resource getSecondSibling() {
        Resource parent = getResource().getParent();
        Resource secondSib = null;
        Iterator<Resource> children = parent.listChildren();

        //find the second child
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            secondSib = children.next();
        return secondSib;
    }
}
```

### Using it in the sightly:

```
<sly data-sly-use.model="Model">${model.secondSibling.propertyName}</sly>
```

Comment: As stated in this answer you really shouldn't rely on the item order. instead you should reference the resource by name.

Comment: I think the OP meant the other sibling instead of second. As @ub1k said, the logic can be modified to negate the original resource based on the name.

Answer (score -1):

Here's another example that i used with converting the content to JSON. The contents of the JSON as parsed Objects and each Object has Attributes.

```
<div data-sly-use.jsonHelper="${'com.service.helpers.JSONHelper'
  @json=model.getRawJson}">

  ${jsonHelper.parsedJSON[item].commodityList[subitem].name}
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this addresses the question

Comment: I tried to show an example to use Sightly in a situation as asked by Ayoub, to retrieve the values if multiple objects or nested objects are involved.

Comment: Ah, I see! That makes sense. The only thing is that this works for nested Objects, but not Resource children, which is the specific that the poster is having problems with.