# How to access parent node properties in sightly?

Tags: aem, sightly

We'l do in cq5(jsp) by accessing currentNode.getParent().getProperties();
How can we do similar thing in sightly?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement a use class extending `WCMUsePojo` class or a sling model that exposes a method that returns you the properties of the parent node/resource.

Refer [here](http://labs.6dglobal.com/blog/2014-11-21/sling-models-for-fun-and-profit/) for sling models, also refer to similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39751000/access-to-a-property-in-a-specific-resource-via-sightly)

Answer (score 0):

You can still access these by `${currentNode.parent.properties}`. Unfortunately this will return a `PropertyIterator` (see [docs](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/spec/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Node.html#getProperties())) and `data-sly-list` does not currently offer support for iterators.

So you will need to implement a Use API helper to gather those into a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Just use
`${currentPage.parent.properties['jcr:title']}` or `${currentPage.parent.title}`